# How to kill a NodeJS child exec process?

Tags: python, node.js, exec, child-process, kill-process

I'm executing a Python program from **NodeJS** using **`exec`** function of **`child_process`** and I wish to kill the process on a button click.
Am using Windows11.

Here is my code :

```js
var process__ = undefined; // this is a global variable

    function executePython(command_line_arguement){
      const exec = require('child_process').exec;
      process__=exec(`python program.py "${command_line_arguement}"`, { encoding: 'utf-8',detached : true }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(`exec error: ${error}, ${stderr}`);
        }else{
        console.log(stdout);
        }
      });

    function onButtonClick(){
        process__.kill('SIGINT');
    }
```

However, this **doesn't** seem to **halt** or **kill** the python process that was triggered.

Any guidance on how to proceed would be appreciable.

**Thanks in advance !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe windows needs a force kill to terminate the process i.e. something  like

```
exec('taskkill /F /T /PID ' + process__.pid);

// F - force terminate
// T - kill all sub-processes
// PID - Process Id that you're targetting
```

See [documentation](https://www.windows-commandline.com/taskkill-kill-process/) for taskkill and the flags